# How to Copy data from one sheet to another based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master dataset in one sheet something like this

[image]

In another sheet I want to extract Data from this Master Data set based on a cell value which will have Department as Criteria.

So ,For example if in sheet 2 I type my my Department criteria as Sales, All the rows with Department as Sales should get populated in Sheet 2.

[image]

Can this be done by excel functions/Macros/VBA ?
Thanks in advance.
Pardon me if you find this query absurd .

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done.  Add this code to a module in your workbook.  You can run it right from the debugger, or go to macros and assign it a hotkey, or you can create a button on the sheet and put this code inside the button click event.  There are probably more efficient ways to do this but it shouldn't matter unless you have a lot of data.  I've been explicit so you can see whats going on.  I've used the sheet names "Data" and "View" you will have to change the names in the code to match your workbook.

EDIT:  I'm also assuming that the top left cell in your screenshot is A1, if not you will have to adjust the code.

```
Sub GetDepartments()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim SourceRow As Long
Dim DeptValue As String
Dim OutputRow As Long
Dim ColCounter As Long

'get size of current view sheet and clear
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("View").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("View").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow > 7 Then
  Set MyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("View").Range("A7:C" & LastRow)
  MyRange.ClearContents
End If

'get size of data sheet
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get value to match
DeptValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("View").Cells(3, 2).Value

'track outputrow
OutputRow = 7

'loop through all rows in data
For SourceRow = 2 To LastRow
  'if match found
  If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(SourceRow, 2).Value = DeptValue Then
    'copy 3 cols
    For ColCounter = 1 To 3
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("View").Cells(OutputRow, ColCounter).Value = _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(SourceRow, ColCounter).Value
    Next ColCounter
    'increment outputrow
    OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
  End If
Next SourceRow
End Sub
```